# javascript Date Picker & Time Picker - Different starting and ending times

Tags: javascript, datepicker, timepicker, ng-zorro-antd

I'm trying to set start time, end time using date picker and time picker (nz-range-picker not nz-date-picker).

I want to set start time 00:00:00 and the end time to this time.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cVsZ.png)

```js
timeDefaultValue = setHours(new Date(), 0, 0, 0);
```

```html
[nzShowTime]="{ nzDefaultOpenValue: timeDefaultValue }"
```

I use setHours, and I succeeded in setting it to 00:00:00.
But it also makes end time to 00:00:00.

Is there a way to set the time individually?

Comment: Which picker library are you using?

Comment: I'm using ng-zorro date-picker.